# Changing color of specific polygons

Tags: qgis

I'm a beginner. I selected 9 polygons. I want to change their color to green. They should stay green after the selection is removed.

[image]

Comment: check out https://docs.qgis.org/2.8/en/docs/training_manual/basic_map/symbology.html

Comment: I don't understand. Can you give the steps how to do it?

Comment: I don't want to change the color of all polygons. I want to change the color of these 7 polygons.

Comment: I want to change the color permanentely only these 9 polygons.

Comment: Add a new attribute and update the value for the selected features green=yes. Then use categorized style.

Comment: I selected 9 polygons. I opened the attribute table. What to do to assign automatically to each selected polygons: yes?

Comment: I managed. I entered 'yes' in the value. I forgot the sign '

Comment: @user30184 please consider converting your comment into an answer so this thread can be marked as answered

Answer (score 1):

**One way:**
-Create\export a new layer from the selected polygons. 
- set the new layer symbolgy & colors the way you choose.
-optional: you can delete the selected polygons is you don't need duplicate ones under.

**Other way:**
If those 9 polygons have a common feature, you can symbolize them by category.
read the user guide here for more info: https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/training_manual/basic_map/symbology.html?highlight=symbology